# Grid onScroll not being called while scrolling

Tags: java, android, gridview

For some reason onScroll is triggered only during grid load and not during the grid scroll action.   Any ideas ?

```
 View view = findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
 GridView gridView = (GridView)view;

 gridView.setOnScrollListener( new GridScrollListener());

        .......
        .....   

public class GridScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
            private  int threshold = 2;
            private int currentpage = 0;
            private int previoustotal = 0;
            private boolean loading = true;

            public GridScrollListener(){}
            public GridScrollListener(int threshold){
                this.threshold = threshold;
            }

            //public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                Log.e(TAG,""+totalItemCount);
                if(loading){
                    if(totalItemCount > previoustotal){
                        loading = false;
                        previoustotal = totalItemCount;
                        currentpage++;
                    }
                }
                if(!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + threshold)){
                    loading = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }
        };
```

Comment: Do you get no LogCat output?

Comment: @AlexT. none, I set a breakpoint there , it hits the breakpoint during load but not during scroll.

Comment: @AlexT. To clarify , there is output during grid load but not during grid scrolling.